# Is the LASSO also a subset selection method?

Tags: feature-selection, lasso

I have got a question about the LASSO regularisation method, this method is usually used in machine learning and multivariate statistics to avoid the overfitting and hence, get better predictions. The "penalised" log-likelihood of a LASSO model is given by:

$\underset{\beta}{\text{argmax}} \qquad l(\beta)  - \lambda \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{p}\left | \beta _{j} |\right. $

where $l$ is the log-likelihood and $\beta$ are the regression coefficient. Usually the size of the regression coefficients included in the fitted model are shrink. However, I have seen some publications that use the "full" sized chosen parameters later on in a model, instead of the "shrink" sized parameters. Thus, they are using the LASSO as a subset selection method akin to univariate analysis. Would you agree that that is not a correct approach?

Comment: There have been some related discussions here, you might search for them with the right keywords. Perhaps this exact question has not been asked, but some related ones have been.

Comment: Look for "relaxed LASSO".

Comment: Hi,  yes I see what you mean. I checked the relaxed LASSO and it is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.